# Greedily assigning scores to maximize the final result

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

You are given a time line of T days and a list of N scores. You have to assign each score to a day(among 1 to T) such that the total assigned score maximizes.

Although there are restrictions. Each score can be assigned to only a limited number of days X and also can be assigned to days occuring on or  after a particular number Y.

Input is in the given Format :

T

N

Score X Y (150 4 1 means Score 150 can be assigned to atmost 4 days on or after day 1)

For eg :

```
T = 10             

N = 5

150 4 1

120 4 3

200 2 7

100 10 5

50 5 1
```

Note = 2 Scores can have same value . Each day can be assigned at most 1 score.

The optimum result for above example would be : 150 150 150 150 120 120 200 200 120 120.

What i tried :

I sorted the list according to the scores and started assigning the highest scores first.

In the above example I would start with 200 and assign it to 7 and 8 days.

Similarly I would assign the next highest score 150 to 1,2,3 and 4 days.
and so on ...

But this would take O(N * T) time. N for iterting over list of scores and T for checking and assigning scores over the time line(in the worst case).

The goal is to maximise and calculate the final score.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Like without even assigning the scores and thus doing away with the T part of O(N * T).

Comment: That is imho pretty pessimistic, because most of the time you only have to iterate over a small portion of T. On average you should be pretty close to  O(T)

Comment: @MikeMB Can you please explain why? The N factor would obviously come because of the iteration over N sorted scores

Comment: Are you interested in minimizing the actual runtime of your algorithm? In that case it would help if you showed the actual code.

Comment: No, actually my algorithm would guarantee a bad runtime , so the aim of this question is to find another optimum approach to get the solution.
Since I know the above algo would not work , I am still thinking of various approaches and haven't coded any of them

Comment: *"would not work"* - for what? What is the upper limit for T and N? Do you have a link to the original question / a meaningufl dataset? I'd like to test a few ideas.

Comment: Hi MikeMB , the question is from a text book so the link would not be possible , T and N are both < 10^5 . So O(10^10) would not work , I aim to optimise this time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded up a pretty straight forward implementation of your algorithm:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

constexpr int T = 10;
struct Item {
    int score;
    int count;
    int min;
};
std::array<Item, 5> input={{
    {150, 4, 1},
    {120, 4, 3},
    {200, 2, 7},
    {100, 10, 5},
    {50, 5, 1}
}};
std::array<bool, T> days{};

int main() {
    // preprocess input
    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end(), [](auto l, auto r) {return l.score > r.score; });

    int totalScore = 0;
    int lastFreeDay = T - 1;

    [&] {
        for (auto spec : input) {
            // scan forward to find open spots for the scores
            for (int pos = spec.min-1; spec.count && pos < lastFreeDay; ++pos) {
                if (!days[pos]) {
                    days[pos] = true;
                    totalScore += spec.score;
                    spec.count--;
                }
            }
            // we weren't able to assign all scores of this entry,
            // so every day after spec.min has already a score assigned to it.
            // lets scan backward and see where the last free one is
            if (spec.count > 0) {
                lastFreeDay = spec.min;
                while (days[lastFreeDay]) {
                    if (--lastFreeDay == -1) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }();

    return totalScore;
}
```

I'm not sure what the exact algorithmic complexity is, but you can see two things:

- At the beginning, there are very few collisions, so the inner loop doesn't actually depend on `T`, so it behaves more like O(N*k) (where k is the average number of times you can assign a particular score).
- Even if N grows very large, not all scores can actually be processed, because the algorithm can terminate early and compares the latest free day against the earliest da a score can be assigned to.

Of course, you can create an worst case input, where you have T*(T+1)/2 passes of the inner loop (for N == T and k = 1 and min_i = 1) but my gut feeling is that on average it is much better than O(N*T) or at least has a very small constant (actually, the sort could be the dominant factor).

Long story short: I'm pretty confident that your algorithm is in fact applicable in practice and could probably be further improved by more intelligent data structures as suggested by Prune.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain a table of available intervals, I believe that you can keep this to **O**(N + T).  Don't range through the entire length `T` each time; just check your list of open intervals and begin at the first available interval that contains the input line's `Y` value.  There will be no more than N/2 intervals in this "open" list, and either hashing or a binary search can keep the complexity under control.

Comment: Hi Prune , can you suggest how can I handle the open intervals in c++. what data structure to use and how to work with them

Comment: @Ravikishan: You could use a self-balancing binary tree (such as an RB-tree). It would be sufficient to store the beginning point of each interval in the tree. I think that makes the complexity O(T log T) (sorting the scores is O(T log T), so you're not losing anything) because finding an element in a balanced search tree of size M is O(log M).